# Issue with XML formatting (fso.write, CreateTextFile)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to send via Excel VBA data via a SOAP call to a webservice. Initially I built a version which works and is based on quite a decent amount of code lines but in concept took data from various excel tabs (*inout, connection details, codelists*) with help from `CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")` to send the data and `CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument)"` to store the response back into a XML.

All worked fine except for large quantities of lines. When the Excel sheet Input has more than 250 lines than the processing time (CPU load) is high and takes about 6-7 minutes in which the application 'hangs'. With help from other post I rebuilt the code to use `fso.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` and use `fso.CreateTextFile` to write the file immediately and not take the data into memory first. But now I run into a 'snag'. When I create the XML file (before sending it via the SOAP service) and open it in any browser I can only see that data itself and not the nodes. Where as if I open an XML create the old way then it shows perfectly. When opening the files in Notepad++ they seem to me as the same but somehow they are not.

And this brings me to the biggest problem. When the XML is created (in the new way) then the connection is established but I get an error from the webservice. I believe this has to do with the fact that the `MyDom = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument"): myDOM.load (myxml)` does not see the nodes but pure data like the brower does.

I've already tried several ways and used the old XML files to send them via the webserice call. Tried also to add a blank line at the bottom but I do not understand the problem nor do I know how I can make the `MyDom = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument"): MyDom (myXML)` visible to me so I can see what it is trying to post. Hence my question to you and see if you have idea's.

Here is a shortened version of the code to create the XML file:

```
Function CallWS()

'*****************************
Dim StartTimeCreateXML As Double
Dim SecondsElapsedCreateXML As Double

'Remember time when macro starts
  StartTimeCreateXML = Timer

'***************************** 

    '==CLEAR CELLS WITH IDs AND WARNINGS
    Call ClearCellsIDs

    '==TURN SCREENUPDATE OFF
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '==Declare our working variables
    Dim sMsg As String
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim LogSetting As String
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim oFile As Object

    '==DEFINE XMLHTTP
    Dim ObjHTTP As Object
    Set ObjHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")

    '==DEFINE XMLDOCPOST and XMLDOCRESP
    Set XMLdocPost = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    Set XMLdocResp = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

    '==DEFINITIONS
    sURL = Sheets("Connection").Range("I13")
    Client = Sheets("Connection").Range("I14")
    User = Sheets("Connection").Range("I15") & "@" & Client
    Password = Sheets("Connection").Range("I16")
    OperationMode = Sheets("Connection").Range("I20")
    LogSetting = Sheets("Connection").Range("I21").Value

    '==CREATE UNIQUE ID FOR CONSIGNMENT AND DELIVERY
    myEori = Sheets("Connection").Range("I22").Value
    MyTimeString = Format(Now, "yyyymmddhhmmss")

    myGenID = myEori & "-" & MyTimeString

    '==DEFINE FSO AND OFILE
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\TEST\2.B. Project Excel SOAP\SOMECUSTOMER\1a. Development XMLsource\Temp2.xml", True)

    '==WE CREATE OUR XML FOR SUBMISSION TO THE WEB SERVICE

    oFile.Write "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">" & vbCrLf
    oFile.Write "    <soap:Body>" & vbCrLf
    oFile.Write "        <createConsignment xmlns=""urn:de.aeb.xnsg.ic.bf"">" & vbCrLf
    oFile.Write "           <request xmlns="""">" & vbCrLf
    oFile.Write "           <Test1>TEST1</Test1>" & vbCrLf
    oFile.Write "           <Test2>TEST2</Test2>" & vbCrLf
    oFile.Write "        </createConsignment>" & vbCrLf
    oFile.Write "    </soap:Body>" & vbCrLf
    oFile.Write "</soap:Envelope>" 
'END XML CREATION
'=============================================================================
    'CLOSE OFILE
    oFile.Close

    '==TURN SCREENUPDATE BACK ON
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    '==CLEAN UP CODE
    Set ObjHTTP = Nothing
    Set xmldoc = Nothing

End Function
```

And here is the webservice call function:

```
Function WebServiceCall()

'*****************************
Dim StartTimeWebServiceCall As Double
Dim SecondsElapsedWebServiceCall As Double

'Remember time when macro starts
  StartTimeWebServiceCall = Timer

'*****************************
'Insert Your Code Here...
    '==DEFINE XMLHTTP
    Dim myHTTP As Object
    Set myHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")

    '==DEFINE XMLDOCPOST and XMLDOCRESP
    Set MyDom = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    Set MyDom = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Dim sURL As String

    sURL = Sheets("Connection").Range("I13")
    Client = Sheets("Connection").Range("I14")
    User = Sheets("Connection").Range("I15") & "@" & Client
    Password = Sheets("Connection").Range("I16")
    OperationMode = Sheets("Connection").Range("I20")
    LogSetting = Sheets("Connection").Range("I21").Value


    'Create the DomDocument Object
    Set MyDom = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

    'Load entire Document before moving on
    MyDom.async = False
    MyDom.Load ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Temp2.xml"

    'wat wordt er gepost?


    'open the connection
    myHTTP.Open "POST", sURL, False
    'We create the SOAP header for submission to the Web service
    myHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    myHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " + Base64Encode(User + ":" + Password)

    'send the XML
    myHTTP.Send (MyDom.XML)

    'Display the response
    MsgBox myHTTP.ResponseText

    '==CLEAN UP CODE
    Set MyDom = Nothing
    Set myHTTP = Nothing

 '*****************************
'Determine how many seconds code took to run
  SecondsElapsedWebServiceCall = Round(Timer - StartTimeWebServiceCall, 2)

'Notify user in seconds
  MsgBox "This code WebServiceCall ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsedWebServiceCall & " seconds", vbInformation
'*****************************

End Function
```

Not all code is mine here and there I copied some code from others for example the sections about the timers.

The error I get from the webservice is:

> Fehler bei XML-Reader: com.ctct.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected
>   EOD in prolog

Comment: The XML you attempt to create is not well-formed as the *request* node does not close. Run the *temp2.xml* through any online XML validator.

Comment: Thanks Parfait, I changed it and tested it again but fails. I digged into it somewhat more and use the XML source in XML to see if I could re-engineer the file in Excel and found out that the special characters are causing the problem. When I remove them from the data then the webserve call is executed just fine.